# Integrate oracle-bmcs-python-sdk in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.5, setup.py, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

I am installing dependencies of my package through setup.py file. If the package is not present in PyPI like oracle-bmcs-python-sdk , then how I can integrate it in my setup.py file. Currently we have public link of oracle bmc sdk:

https://docs.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/tools/ruby/latest/download/oracle-bmcs-ruby-sdk.zip

Now using only above link how can I install oraclebmc sdk from setup.py file ? 
I have tried adding it in dependency_links but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The BMCS Python SDK is [now on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oraclebmc), so adding it to your setup.py script should be the same as how you'd add any other Python package on PyPI.